# Unexpected behavior in entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I ran into what I think is a really odd situation with entity framework.  Basically, if I update an row directly with a sql command, when I retrive that row through linq it doesn't have the updated information.  Please see the below example for more information.

First I created a simple DB table

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Foo (
    Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name varchar(50) NULL
)
```

Then I created a console application to add an object to the DB, update it with a sql command and then retrieve the object that was just created.  Here it is:

```
public class FooContext : DbContext
{

    public FooContext() : base("FooConnectionString")
    {

    }

    public IDbSet<Foo> Foo { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().ToTable("Foo");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}

public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //setup the context
        var context = new FooContext();

        //add the row
        var foo = new Foo()
        {
            Name = "Before"
        };
        context.Foo.Add(foo);
        context.SaveChanges();

        //update the name
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE Foo Set Name = 'After' WHERE Id = " + foo.Id);

        //get the new foo
        var newFoo = context.Foo.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == foo.Id);

        //I would expect the name to be 'After' but it is 'Before'
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The new name is: {0}", newFoo.Name));
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

}
```

The write line at the bottom prints out "Before" however I would expect that it prints out "After".  The odd thing about it is that if I run profiler I see the sql query run and if I run the query in management studio myself, it returns "After" as the name.  I am running sql server 2014.

Can someone please help me understand what is going on here?

UPDATE:

It is going to the database on the FirstOrDefault line.  Please see the attached screen shot from sql profiler.

[image]

So my question really is this:

1) If it is caching, shouldn't it not be going to the DB?  Is this a bug in EF?

2) If it is going to the db and spending the resources, shouldn't EF update the object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FooContext` includes change tracking and caching, so the in-memory object that is returned from your query is the same instance that you added earlier. Calling `SaveChanges()` does clear the context and `FooContext` is not aware of the changes that happened underneath it in the database.

This is usually a good thing -- not making expensive database calls for every operation.

In your sample, try making the same query from a new `FooContext`, and you should see "After".

#### update

Responding to your updated question, yes, you are right. I missed before that you were using `FirstOrDefault()`. If you were using `context.Find(foo.Id)`, as I wrongly assumed, then there would be no query.

As for why the in-memory object is not updated to reflect the change in the database, I'd need to do some research to do anything more than speculate. That said, here is my speculation:

- An instance of the database context cannot return more than one instance of the same entity. Within a unit of work, we must be able to rely on the context to return the *same* instance of the entity. Otherwise, we might query by different criteria and get 3 objects representing the same conceptual entity. At that point, how can the context deal with changes to any of them? What if the name is changed to a different value on two of them and then `SaveChanges()` is called -- what should happen?
- Given then that the context tracks at most a single instance of each entity, why can't EF just update that entity at the point at which a query is executed? EF could even discard that change if there is a pending in-memory change, since it knows about those changes.

  - I think one part of the answer is that diffing all the columns on large entities and in large result sets is performance prohibitive.
  - I think a bigger part of the answer is that it executing a simple SELECT statement should not have the potential to cause side effects throughout the system. Entities may be grouped or looped over by the value of some property and to change the value of that property at an indeterminate time and as a result of a SELECT query is highly unsound.

Comment: yup, it's the cache, can also use `context.Foo.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault` on the same context

Comment: Jay, thanks for the answer.  I guess my follow up question is this: I understand that it has a cached object but something could have changed outside of it.  It you already went to the DB and ran a query, why not just updated the cached object with the new in-memory one?

Comment: @zgirod The second query (the fetch) does not go to the database at all because you are asking for an item (by Id) that the context already knows about.

On another note, if you made another change to the EF object and tried to save changes, you'd get an exception because of optimistic concurrency and the changes made outside of EF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/JJ592904.aspx

Comment: @Jay please see the updated question.  It IS going to the DB on the FirstOrDefault line.  I see the query when I run sql profiler.  That is what I find so confusing.  To me EF either shouldn't go to the DB because it is cached or go to the DB and update the object.  In this case, EF is going to the DB but isn't updating the object.  Weird!

Comment: @Jay you the man!  Thanks and wish I could upvote more than once.